# Открытие wav файла

Tags: python, файлы, файловый-ввод-вывод, wav

У меня есть данный код:

```
import wave, struct
bad = False
wf = wave.open('recorded.wav', 'wb')

wf.setnchannels(channels) wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(sample_rate) 
if randint(0, 2) == 1:
    bad = False
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(get_one())) else:
    data = []
    r = sample_rate
    if not bad:
        data.extend([3263 for i in range(850)])
        bad = True
        r -= 850
    for i in range(r):
        data.append(0)
    wf.writeframes(struct.pack('<' + str(len(data)) + 'h', *data)) wf.close()
```

Раньше всё работало, но сейчас при запуске кода выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\BadConn\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    bad = loop(bad)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\BadConn\engine.py", line 36, in loop
    wf = wave.open('recorded.wav', 'wb')
  File "C:\Python310\lib\wave.py", line 511, in open
    return Wave_write(f)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\wave.py", line 304, in __init__
    f = builtins.open(f, 'wb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'recorded.wav'
Exception ignored in: <function Wave_write.__del__ at 0x000001C3FDE3D630>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\wave.py", line 326, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\wave.py", line 443, in close
    if self._file:
AttributeError: 'Wave_write' object has no attribute '_file'
```

В чём заключается ошибка и как её исправить? PermissionError пробовал убрать, запуская через консоль с правами администратора, но не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы не закрываете файл. Если забываете закрывать файл, используйте лучше менеджер контекста, чтобы файл закрывался автоматически:

```
with wave.open('recorded.wav', 'wb') as wf:
    ...
```

2. Проверьте, что файл не занят другой программой - например, предыдущим запуском вашего же скрипта, не закрывшего файл, либо какой-то программой, которой вы сгенерированный файл потом открыли.
3. Проверьте, из какого каталога вы запускаете скрипт. Без явного указания пути записи файла, файл будет создаваться в текущем каталоге запуска скрипта (это не обязательно каталог, где расположен сам скрипт, вы можете его запускать, находясь в совсем другом каталоге). Даже у администратора (локального) может не быть прав на запись в некоторые каталоги (например, в какие-то сетевые каталоги).